# "Стоп, самострой!" Ставить ли запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

"Стоп, самострой!" Ставить ли запятую?

Answer (score 4):

**СТОП**. [от англ. stop - останавливать]. I. межд. Употр. **как команда для прекращения** движения, работы; стой!, остановись! С. машина! // Употр. **как приказ:** довольно!, хватит!, прекрати! С., прервём на этом разговор.

**Стоп как междометие, возможны различные варианты.**

Стоп самострой! – движение за остановку самостроя.

Стоп самострою! – лозунг.

Стоп, самострой! – обращение.

**Примеры:**

**Стоп Самострой!** Список объектов капитального строительства, 
в отношении которых... зафиксированы нарушения градостроительного, природоохранного и земельного законодательства.

**Стоп** хамскому **самострою**!

Участники мероприятия держали в руках плакаты с надписями «**Стоп, самострой**!».

Answer (score 1):

СТОП. [от англ. stop - останавливать]. I. межд. Употр. как команда для прекращения движения, работы; стой!, остановись! **С. машина**! // Употр. как приказ: довольно!, хватит!, прекрати! С., прервём на этом разговор. 
стать, заглохнуть, остановиться, застопориться, застопорить, встать

**стоп машина**
стать, заглохнуть, остановиться, застопориться, застопорить, встать (
[Словарь синонимов](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/172058/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%))

Очевидно, только "стоп машина" может употребляться без запятых как устойчивое выражение. При этом "стоп, машина" тоже употребимо. Во всех остальных случаях типа "стоп + сущ. в им. п.", например **"стоп, самострой**", **запятая необходима по общим правилам** (стоп - команда, самострой - обращение).

Примеры

Им оказался полный останов ― “**стоп машина**”, ― приключившийся с его Родиной. [Александр Иличевский. Матисс // «Новый Мир», 2007]

Должно быть, раньше он служил в механиках, потому что каждый раз, прежде чем остановиться, кричал себе: «**Стоп, машина**!» и прежде чем пойти дальше: «Полный ход!» А. П. Чехов, «Белолобый», 1895 г

Дополнение 1:

Впрочем, в случае протеста против самостроя я бы предпочел лозунг **"Стоп самострою!"**. Его смысл "Остановить самострой!", и это лучше чем "Стоп, самострой!" (Остановись, самострой!)

Дополнение 2:

Вот ответ справочной службы русского языка (Грамота.ру) на похожий вопрос:

> [Вопрос № 295556](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=295556%20%20%20%20)
>   Нужна ли запятая в выражении "Стоп(,) коррупция!"?
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Да, постановка запятой корректна. Также уместно двоеточие (в значении: нужно обратить внимание на коррупцию). Стоп: коррупция!

Comment: есть еще: ***С. тали*** — прекратить выбирание или травление талей. ***С. шпиль*** — прекратить действие шпиля, застопорить его. ***С. фока-галс (контрабрас)*** — прекратить выбирание фока-галса (контрабраса).

Comment: Очевидно, что возможны варианты. У Sibylla все подробно изложено.

Comment: С. тали и т. п. - устоявшиеся специальные термины. Вопрос, можно ли опускать запятую в обычной речи, можно ли пистать : "Стоп самострой". По-моему, нельзя.

Comment: Ну Сибилия объяснила.

Comment: Если я понял ее правильно, можно и так и так. а почему - непонятно. Соответсвенно, коль Вы на нее ссылаетесь, мне Ваша позиция непонятна. Можете четко сформулировать?

Comment: – М_Г Sibylla в зависимости от смысла возможны варианта. В первом варианте нет запятой потому что и нет обращения.

Comment: @Серж, Sibylla, Если нет запятой и нет обращения, то сделайте  разбор этого предложения, это внесет ясность.

Comment: А чем отличается термин от свободного словосочетания? По сути он тоже образовался от свободного словосочетания. Но ведь там нет запятой. Стоп самострой  можно цельное название.  В нем нет обращения.

Comment: @Серж По общим правилам слова в сочетании должны быть связаны каким-либо способом (согласование, управление,примыканием). Покажите, каким способом звязаны наши слова. Если нет такой связи, то как это объяснить?

Comment: –@М_Г, только увидел вас вопрос. Думаю, в данном случае можно условно подвести под примыкание.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ Gramma.ru

Пунктуационное оформление сочетаний со словом "стоп" является неустойчивым. В словарях отмечается употребление "стоп" в качестве междометия "как команда для прекращения движения, остановки в значении стой, остановись" и в качестве сказуемого "для обозначения остановки, прекращения движения, работы". Во втором значении слово "стоп" не предусматривает возможность распространения другими словами, ср.: Прохор сразу - стоп - снял шапку и перекрестился (Шишков, Угрюм-река).

Первоначально существительное в Им. п., стоящее после слова "стоп", рассматривалось только как обращение, поэтому регулярно отделялось запятой. Это касается и фразы "Стоп машина", которая писалась с запятой: "Стоп, машина!", так как это было командой, обращенной машинному отделению (метонимически - "машина"). (Ср. аналогичное употребление: Я не преувеличиваю, и мне не изменяет память: в тот момент, когда сцена была сыграна и снята, Лариса с криком «Стоп, камера!» [Ю. И. Визбор. Когда все были вместе (1980-1983)].) В связи с переосмыслением значения фразы и ее фразеологизацией она стала писаться без запятой. Однако на другие случаи употребления существительных в Им. п. после слова "стоп" это оформление должно распространяться автоматически. Таким образом, среди предложенных Вами вариантов правильным следует признать вариант "Стоп, самострой!".

Слово "стоп" может распространяться и существительным в Д. п. Например: ...Дать бы красный / по всей планете: / Стоп войне! Осторожно - / дети! (Ю. Друнина. Ты рядом. М., 1964. С. 93). Возможно, эта возможность появилась под влиянием близкой по значению конструкции со словом "нет", ср.: Стоп войне / Нет войне. Исходя из этого, можно допустить оформление конструкции "Стоп самострою!".